# Powershell replace reformats CSV

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

I have a csv that I want to remove a few characters from for further processing.  I've done this many times before using the regex -replace method, but this time it seems to be messing up the whole csv.  I'm using:

```
$Removed_Characters=$Good_CSV|%{$_ -replace "X",""}
```

Instead of the same csv without the "X" character, this outputs a series of arrays, one for each row (ie `@{Name=Tom, ID=12}@{Name=Bill, ID=15}`...).  This is not at all what I want, and not what I've seen in the past.  What could I be doing differently?

Comment: I'm not clear if "reformats" is an important part of your question, or a typo.  Do you want to remove or replace text in the CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to replace a string in any property of an object array (from import-csv) but you may just be intending to replace a string in a single value.

The script you have provided is converting each object to a string and then perform a string-wise replace on that string value. Giving you what looks like a hash of the object properties.

### Replace a string from a particular field in a CSV

```
@"
Name,ID
Tom,12
Joe,15
"@ | out-file test.csv
$CSVFile = import-csv test.csv 
$CSVFile | %{$_.name = $_.name -replace 'o','i'}
$CSVFile
#Name ID
#---- --
#Tim  12
#Jie  15
```

### Replace a string from any field in a CSV

```
$Properties = $CSVFile | get-member -membertype noteproperty | select -expand name
$CSVFile | %{
    $entry=$_; 
    foreach ($prop in $Properties) {
        $entry.$prop = $entry.$prop -replace 'o|1','i'
    }
}
$CSVFile
#Name ID
#---- --
#Tim  i2
#Jie  i5
```

Note that replacing values on all properties is also converting all those values to strings, so you could be losing fidelity (dates etc).

Good Luck!

Shane

Comment: Thanks, this works!  I looked through some old scripts and found what I used to do.  I answered with that below.  Even though my way looks worse, I actually found it to be ~2.5x faster with `measure-command`

Comment: Your way works, and will definitely be faster, just be aware that your regex might break the CSV file if you aren't careful change heading rows/removing data if you replace a ',' accidentally. etc.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is using `get-content` to import the csv as a string.

```
$Good_CSV | export-csv $out -notypeinformation
$replaced=(gc $out).replace("X","")
$replaced|convertfrom-csv|export-csv $final_out -notypeinformation
```

Using regex replace is much simpler on a giant string than on a csv object.